# How to prove $\lim_{z \rightarrow 1} \frac{2z + 1}{z + 2}=1.$

Tags: limits, complex-numbers

> I am trying to prove $$\lim_{z \rightarrow 1} \frac{2z + 1}{z + 2}=1.$$

---

From the definition, given $\epsilon > 0$, I need to determine $\delta > 0$ such that $0< |z-1| <\delta$ implies $| \frac{2z + 1}{z + 2} - 1|<\epsilon$. 
Doing a little bit of algebra I need to prove.
 $$\delta<\epsilon |z+2|$$

Any Hints!

Answer (score 2):

Use the fact that $\displaystyle \left| \frac{2z+1}{z+2} - 1 \right| = \left| \frac{z-1}{z+2} \right|.$

If $|z - 1| < 1$ then $|z+2| = |3 + (z-1)| \ge 3 - |z-1| \ge 2$, and if, **in addition**, $|z-1| < 2\epsilon$ then $$\left| \frac{z-1}{z+2} \right| < \frac{2\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon.$$

This means that if simultaneously $|z-1| < 1$ and $|z-1| < 2\epsilon$, then  $\displaystyle \left| \frac{2z+1}{z+2} - 1 \right| < \epsilon.$

You can take $\delta = \min\{1,2\epsilon\}$.